# IPFS for collaborative text editing

Tags: reactjs, ipfs, crdt, collaborative-editing

I am new to ReactJS and IPFS, trying to create webpages with textarea where, when I type in textarea of webpage 1 it should reflect on the other and vice versa. Also, I need to do this with ipfs. Any help in understanding how to proceed on this. I tried installing yjs, http-server and ipfs. used textarea binding, but couldn't able to replicate. Help me with steps on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have access to some good examples on how to do this, see:

- Decentralized Real-Time Collaborative Documents https://blog.ipfs.io/30-js-ipfs-crdts.md
- The video tutorial of the above post https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kdx8rJd8rQ
- Here is a fully built app that uses the tech above https://peerpad.net